# How to formulate this problem in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Say, I have the following expressions

```
f = R[p]
g = S[p]
```

where R,S are rational functions, and I want to find a polynomial such that

```
P[f,g]=C(onstant)
```

For example:

```
f=p^2 + p
g=p+4
```

leading to

```
P(x,y)=y^2-x-7y
g^2-f-7g=-12.
```

Can Mathematica help me in any way finding the polynomial P, if R,S become more and more complex ( but still rational, of course )?

And, at least, how can I find the answer to the example with Mathematica?

Comment: Just to start the ball rolling. The constant can be computed as `-Resultant[f,g,p]`.

Comment: The constant is not unique.  P may be multiplied by a constant. And as the constant can be incorporated into P  it  can always be chosen as zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by making a list of polynomial terms to choose from: for example, all terms up to third order in $f$ and $g$,

```
terms = DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[{1, F, G}, 3]]
(*    {1, F, G, F^2, F G, G^2, F^3, F^2 G, F G^2, G^3}    *)
```

Express these terms as polynomials in $p$, and list their polynomial coefficients (here up to sixth order in $p$):

```
f = p^2 + p;
g = p + 4;
X = CoefficientList[terms /. {F -> f, G -> g}, p, 7]
(*    {{ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
       { 0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0},
       { 4,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
       { 0,  0,  1,  2,  1,  0,  0},
       { 0,  4,  5,  1,  0,  0,  0},
       {16,  8,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0},
       { 0,  0,  0,  1,  3,  3,  1},
       { 0,  0,  4,  9,  6,  1,  0},
       { 0, 16, 24,  9,  1,  0,  0},
       {64, 48, 12,  1,  0,  0,  0}}    *)
```

Find the null-space of this matrix: the polynomials that combine to zero,

```
NullSpace[Transpose[X]] . terms
(*    {84 - 7 F - 37 G - F G + G^3,
       12 F - F^2 - 7 F G + F G^2,
       12 - F - 7 G + G^2}             *)
```

Verify these three solutions:

```
% /. {F -> f, G -> g} // Expand
(*    {0, 0, 0}    *)
```

So we have the solutions
$$
-f g-7 f+g^3-37 g+84 = 0\\
-f^2+f g^2-7 f g+12 f = 0\\
-f+g^2-7 g+12 = 0
$$

There will be many more solutions if you increase the order of terms in `terms`. [Factoring](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) these solutions will show you the minimal function $P$, which in this case is $P(f,g)=-f+g^2-7 g+12=0$. You can add constants $C$ to this solution at will.

### Rational functions

An extension of the above procedure to rational functions is straightforward through extending all functions by the common denominator. As an example,

```
f = p/(p + 1);
g = p*(p - 1)/(p^3 + 7);
denom = PolynomialLCM @@ Denominator /@ {f, g}
(*    (1 + p) (7 + p^3)    *)
```

Expanding the rational functions by the `denom` gives polynomials of order

```
e = Max@Exponent[{f, g}*denom, p]
(*    4    *)
```

Use polynomial terms up to fifth order in the result:

```
maxorder = 5;
terms = DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[{1, F, G}, maxorder]]
(*    {1, F, G, F^2, F G, G^2, F^3, F^2 G, F G^2, G^3, F^4, F^3 G,
       F^2 G^2, F G^3, G^4, F^5, F^4 G, F^3 G^2, F^2 G^3, F G^4, G^5}    *)
```

Compute the coefficients matrix:

```
X = CoefficientList[terms*denom^maxorder /. {F -> f, G -> g}, p, e*maxorder + 1]
(*    21x21 matrix with integer coefficients    *)
```

Pick the null-space solution that has the smallest number of non-zero coefficients:

```
MinimalBy[NullSpace[Transpose[X]], Total@*Unitize] . terms
(*    {-F + 3 F^2 - 2 F^3 - 7 G + 21 F G - 21 F^2 G + 6 F^3 G}    *)
```

So we see that
$$
6 f^3 g-21 f^2 g-2 f^3+3 f^2+21 f g-f-7 g = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you! - What an interesting answer. I need to study it first, of course. After that I might have a, more complicated, follow-up question to post.